# shell script not executable remote server

Tags: linux, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        file= ls /etc/apache2/sites-available | grep $1
        if [ $file ="true" ]; then
                cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
                path= grep DocumentRoot $1 | awk '{gsub("\"","",$2); print $2}'
                print $path
        else
                echo "not in server"
        fi

fi
enter code here
```

When it is running into a local or server they give the perfect output but when the shell script running into a remote server it is not running

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        for HOST in ${HOSTS_WEBMODULE_DEV}; do
                ssh root@$HOST bash -c "
                cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
                path= grep DocumentRoot $1 | awk '{gsub("\"","",$2); print $2}'

                "
        done
```

when script run into remote server the error is

```
bash: -c: option requires an argument
awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(",,); print }
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(",,); print }
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ syntax error
bash: -c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bash: -c: line 3: `     fi'
```

Comment: What happens when it runs on the remote server? Does it produce an error? Does it run without doing anything?

Comment: yes it is give the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself the trouble of correct escaping and let the bash do it for you:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# The function you want to run on the remote side
myfunc() {
  cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
  # Correctly assign the variable
  path=$(grep DocumentRoot "$1" | awk '{gsub("\"","",$2); print $2}')
  # Correctly print the variable
  echo "$path"
}

# Copy the function definition to the remote, then invoke it with
# the script's $1, correctly escaped.
ssh "root@$HOST" "$(declare -f myfunc); myfunc ${1@Q}"
```

Comment: it is not working error is declare: not found

Comment: Make sure you are running the script correctly with `./yourscript` and not with `sh yourscript`